# Swift and Realm: getting Thread 1: signal SIGABRT when add objects in list

Tags: swift, swift3, realm

I define three classes:

CoffeeBrand:

```
dynamic var brandName = ""
let brands = List<Coffee>()
```

Coffee:

```
dynamic var name = ""
let cupAmount = List<CoffeeCup>()
```

CoffeeCup:

```
dynamic var cup = 0
dynamic var caffeine = 0
```

And wanna try it so I add a brand Starbucks to try how it will be like in the table viewed

```
class CoffeeListsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    var brands: Results<CoffeeBrand>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let Starbucks = CoffeeBrand(value: ["Starbucks",["Iced Latte", [200,150],[500,150]]])

        try! realm.write() {
            realm.add(Starbucks)
        }
    }
}
```

But what I got is "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT", and I checked that I think this should working without thread 1(which I google and try to find what's wrong from others' questiones)

With in the table data source of this:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return brands.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    //let cellIdentifier = "CoffeeBrandTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CoffeeBrandTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CoffeeBrandTableViewCell
    // in my cell, only a label of brandName
    let brandList = brands[indexPath.row]   
    cell.brandName.text = brandList.brandName
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of that code, you're not ever assigning a value to `brands`. Since you're declaring brands as explicitly unwrapped, that might be causing an issue.

```
class CoffeeListsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    let brands = try! Realm().objects(CoffeeBrand.self)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

As an aside, `realm.add` adds a new object to the Realm database each time it is called. In your current code there, you're adding a new copy of the Starbucks object every time the view controller loads. It would be more appropriate to add more control on when adding objects to Realm.

Comment: Nope， that's not the problem, I try this before, and it gets "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"